# Linear Diophantine Equations with Restriction in the GAP System

Tags: gap-system, diophantine

I am searching for a way to use the GAP System to find a solution of a linear Diophantine equation over the non-negative integers. Explicitly, I have a list `L` of positive integers for each of which there exists a solution of the linear Diophantine equation `s = 11*a + 7*b` such that `a` and `b` are non-negative integers. I would like to have the GAP System return for each element `s` of `L` the ordered pair(s) `[a, b]` corresponding to the above solution(s).

I am familiar already with the command `SolutionIntMat` in the GAP System; however, this produces only *some* solution of the linear Diophantine equation `s = 11*a + 7*b`. Particularly, it is possible (and far more likely) that one of the coefficients `a` and `b` is negative. For instance, I obtain the solution `[-375, 600]` when I use the aforementioned command on the linear Diophantine equation `75 = 11*a + 7*b`.

For additional context, this query arises when working with numerical semigroups generated by generalized arithmetic sequences. Use the command `LoadPackage("numericalsgps");` to implement computations with such objects. For instance, if `S := NumericalSemigroup(11, 29, 36, 43, 50, 57, 64, 71);`, then each of the minimal generators of `S` other than `11` is of the form `2*11 + 7*i` for some integer `i in [1..7]`. One can ask the GAP System for the `SmallElements(S);`, and the GAP System will return all elements of `S` up to `FrobeniusNumber(S) + 1`. Clearly, every element of `S` is of the form `11*a + 7*b` for some non-negative integers `a` and `b`; I would like to investigate what coefficients `a` and `b` arise. In fact, the answer is known (cf. Proposition 2.5 of [this paper](https://personal.math.vt.edu/gmatthews/gas.pdf)); I am just trying to get an understanding of the intuition behind the proof.

Thank you in advance for your time and consideration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dylan, thank you for your query and for using `GAP` and `numericalsgps`.

You can probably use in this setting `Factorizations` from the package `numericalsgps`. It internally rewrites the output of `RestrictedPartitions`.
For instance, in your example, you can get all possible "factorizations" of the small elements of `S`, with respect to the generators of `S`, by typing  `List(SmallElements(S), x->[x,Factorizations(x,S)])`. A particular example:

```
gap> Factorizations(104,S);
[ [ 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 ], 
  [ 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 ], [ 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 ] ]
```

If you want to see the factorizations of the elements of `S` in terms of 11 and 7, then you can do the following:

```
gap> FactorizationsIntegerWRTList(29,[11,7]);
[ [ 2, 1 ] ]
```

So, for all minimal generators of `S` you would do

```
gap> List(MinimalGenerators(S), g-> FactorizationsIntegerWRTList(g,[11,7]));
[ [ [ 1, 0 ] ], [ [ 2, 1 ] ], [ [ 2, 2 ] ], [ [ 2, 3 ] ], 
  [ [ 2, 4 ] ], [ [ 2, 5 ] ], [ [ 2, 6 ] ], [ [ 2, 7 ] ] ]
```

For the set of small elements of `S`, try `List(SmallElements(S), g-> FactorizationsIntegerWRTList(g,[11,7]))`. If you only want up to some integer, just replace `SmallElements(S)` with `Intersection([1..200], S)`; or if you want the first, say 200, elements of `S`, use `S{[1..200]}`.

You may want to have a look at [Chapter 9](https://gap-packages.github.io/numericalsgps/doc/chap9_mj.html) of the manual, and in particular to `FactorizationsElementListWRTNumericalSemigroup`.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Pedro, it is wonderful to hear from you! I greatly appreciate your answer. It is exactly what I needed! I had searched the manual, but I was not aware of the correct terminology of "factorization" versus "representation." Thanks again for your very detailed and helpful comment!

Comment: Dylan, yes, in many papers we use representation or even expression, but we preferred to use factorization in this case as it used to measure some nonunique factorization invariants with additive notation

Comment: @Dylan, just wanted to draw your attention to our next meeting on numerical semigroups (online participation will be possible): https://www.ugr.es/~imns2010/2022. There will be some talks about "factorizations".

Comment: Pedro, thank you very much for sharing with me! This looks like a wonderful opportunity to get some more exposure to the current body of research related to numerical semigroups. I would love to attend online, and I will reach out via the contact email provided. Thank you!